# A question about $\pi$-system.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system and use $\mathcal{S}$ to denote the intersection of all $\lambda$-systems containing $\mathcal{P}$. I want to show $\mathcal{S}$ is also a $\pi$-system. By definition, take $A,B\in \mathcal{S}$ and show $A\cap B\in \mathcal{S}$.

Let $\mathcal{A}:=\{C\subseteq X\mid A\cap C\in S\}$, it suffices to show $B\in\mathcal{A}$. If I can show $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\lambda$-system containing $\mathcal{P}$, this completes the proof. I can already show $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\lambda$-system, but I can't show $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$.

Could anyone give me some help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is just for clarification, but has this doubt come from analysing the proof of a larger theorem? (I think the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, if I were pushed to state which one)

Comment: Why make it so difficult? If $\mathcal P’$ is a $\pi$-system containing $\mathcal P$, then $A,B \in \mathcal P’$, and this implies that $A \cap B \in \mathcal P’$. Hence, $A \cap B \in \mathcal S$. Isn’t?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer yeah, I met this question when I read pi-lambda theorem

Comment: Thanks @BowenL, that will be helpful to others reading up about the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem. For convenience, I will edit the tags in your question to make it more accessible. Having said that, I get the feeling your question has been answered before, but will leave the task of finding a duplicate to someone currently having more time than me. I don't really think this is a question in real analysis, more measure theory and probability (where sigma-algebras are likely to be introduced)

Comment: @azif00, no since we don’t know that $P’$ is a $\pi$ system. 

This question is asking the hard part of the $\pi \lambda$ Theorem since a $\lambda$ system is $\pi$ if and only if it’s $\sigma$. You can find a proof of that anywhere - here’s one: https://www.math.lsu.edu/~sengupta/7360f09/DynkinPiLambda.pdf

Comment: @Eric You’re right. I didn’t read carefully the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this in just two simple steps. First fix $D \in \mathcal P$ and consider $\{A\subseteq X: A \cap D \in \mathcal S\}$. This is a  $\lambda$ system containimng $\mathcal P$ and hence it contains $\mathcal S$. Thus, $A \in \mathcal S, D \in \mathcal P$ imlies $ A\cap D \in \mathcal S$. Now Fix $A \in \mathcal S$ and consider $\{D\subseteq X: A \cap D \in \mathcal S\}$. This is a $\lambda$ system containing $\mathcal P$ and so it contains $\mathcal S$. Thus, $A\cap D \in \mathcal S$ whenever $A$ and $D$ in $\mathcal S$.
[As mentioned by OP, it was enough to say $A \in \mathcal S, D \in \mathcal P$ imlies $ A\cap D \in \mathcal S$].

Comment: Thanks for your answering, but why we need the second step, I think your first step may already answer my question: I need to show for any $A\in\mathcal{S},D\in\mathcal{P}$, we have $A\cap D\in\mathcal{S}$. Is there anything wrong with my understanding?

Comment: You are right. I just completed the proof of the fact that $\mathcal S$ is a $\pi$ system. @BowenL

Comment: So sorry, I may click the wrong vote, could you edit anywhere so I can change my vote, sorry to bother u.

Comment: @BowenL I have edited.